# Foreground Notification showing numbers instead of message in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was testing Push Notification from **Firebase console**

I succesfully recieved Notification when my App is in **Background**

[image]

But while in **foreground** whatever message I send the Notification message showing to me is like :

[image]

I dont know from where this **Number** is coming from.

Below is my code for **creating notification :**

```
     override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(p0)

    p0.notification?.let {
        val notif = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "12345")
            .setContentTitle(p0.from)
            .setContentText(p0.to)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_send)
            .build()
        val manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
            .notify(0, notif)
    }
}
```

Below is the screenshot from **Firebase Console :**

[image]

Can someone tell me how I can receive my messages properly.

**UPDATE:**
Also why this difference in **background & foreground notifications**

**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: How are you sending data in notification ? As payload

Comment: @MD updated my question,  please check

Comment: You can get **title** = `message.notification.title` and **body** = `message.notification.body` in side `onMessageReceived`

Answer (score 2):

You're sending  Notification Message. You can get title and body as per below

```
override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(p0)

    val title = message.notification.title
    val body= message.notification.body

    p0.notification?.let {
        val notif = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "12345")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_send)
            .build()
        val manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
            .notify(0, notif)
    }
```

You can get more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: Hi MD can you please answer my UPDATE basically I wanted to know that.So that I can accept your answer

Comment: Soryy, but i wanted to know why I am able to get proper message in background but  the same code is giving some other message in forground

Answer (score 1):

The data is coming from the variable `p0`

Specifically

```
.setContentTitle(p0.from)
.setContentText(p0.to)
```

To get the data/payload from a Remote Message you need to use the method `getData()`

So your overall notification creation looks something like

```
// Check if message contains a notification payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.d("Notification", "Message Notification called ");
    if (remoteMessage.getData().get("action") != null) {
        remoteNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("action"), remoteMessage.getData().get("arg"));
        return;
    }
```